# How to change Neovim Telescope live grep preview entries limit?

Tags: neovim, vimgrep, telescope.nvim

I grep for a keyword in Telescope live grep in Neovim and it shows me that it occurs in 997 places (in multiple files). However, I cannot scroll through all of the matches as the grep window cycles allowing around 100 matches to be previewed. I actually have to quickly run through all of them but the preview window just cycles on much smaller number. Is there any configuration option for it in Telescope?

Here is my (default) telescope config:

```
local options = {
  defaults = {
    vimgrep_arguments = {
      "rg",
      "-L",
      "--color=never",
      "--no-heading",
      "--with-filename",
      "--line-number",
      "--column",
      "--smart-case",
    },
    prompt_prefix = "   ",
    selection_caret = "  ",
    entry_prefix = "  ",
    initial_mode = "insert",
    selection_strategy = "reset",
    sorting_strategy = "ascending",
    layout_strategy = "horizontal",
    layout_config = {
      horizontal = {
        prompt_position = "top",
        preview_width = 0.55,
        results_width = 0.8,
      },
      vertical = {
        mirror = false,
      },
      width = 0.87,
      height = 0.80,
      preview_cutoff = 120,
    },
    file_sorter = require("telescope.sorters").get_fuzzy_file,
    file_ignore_patterns = { "node_modules" },
    generic_sorter = require("telescope.sorters").get_generic_fuzzy_sorter,
    path_display = { "truncate" },
    winblend = 0,
    border = {},
    borderchars = { "─", "│", "─", "│", "╭", "╮", "╯", "╰" },
    color_devicons = true,
    set_env = { ["COLORTERM"] = "truecolor" }, -- default = nil,
    file_previewer = require("telescope.previewers").vim_buffer_cat.new,
    grep_previewer = require("telescope.previewers").vim_buffer_vimgrep.new,
    qflist_previewer = require("telescope.previewers").vim_buffer_qflist.new,
    -- Developer configurations: Not meant for general override
    buffer_previewer_maker = require("telescope.previewers").buffer_previewer_maker,
    mappings = {
      n = { ["q"] = require("telescope.actions").close },
    },
  },

  extensions_list = { "themes", "terms" },
}

return options
```

I've found only these Telescope tweaks

```
preview:
  - check_mime_type
  - filesize_limit
  - timeout
  - hook(s)
  - treesitter
  - msg_bg_fillchar
  - hide_on_startup
  - ls_short
```

but they do not really address the issue.